# Kendo ui Area Chart with Bubbles

Tags: charts, kendo-ui

HeyThere,
is it possible, to get these "bubbles" from the line chart also on the line from a area chart?

The bubbles from here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/kHp5G/1/

I want to have here:
http://jsfiddle.net/fool/HhFbx/

```
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "area",
        markers: {
            visible: false
        },
        line: {
            width: 6
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define multiple series:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [
    {
      type: "area",
      data: new Array(1, 2, 3, 3.5, 5, 6)
    },
    {
      type: "line",
      data: new Array(3, 4, 5, 4.5, 3, 2)
    }
  ]
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/epodIFu/1/edit